# Failed prop type. Required prop types are undefined in my redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

So I'm learning react and redux and I get this error in the console whenever I load my page. I'm not sure what it means since my store should be connected properly (as far as I know, but obviously it's not).

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in >`Navigation`, but its value is `undefined`.

This is component (shortened to the key parts I think)

```js
Navigation.propTypes = {
    open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    open: state.open,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { shiftContent })(Navigation);
```

My action

```js
export const shiftContent = (open: boolean) => {
    return {
        type: ContentTypes.SHIFT_CONTENT,
        payload: open
    }
}
```

My Reducer:

```js
const initialState = {
    open: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action: IAction) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ContentTypes.SHIFT_CONTENT:
            console.log("shifting Open = " + action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                open: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My combined reducer:

```js
import ContentReducer from './ContentReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    content: ContentReducer
});
```

And where I'm initializing my store:

```js
import rootReducer from './Reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

I tried setting up an initial state for the store like:

```js
const initialStore = {
   open: false
}
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialStore);
```

But that gave me an error as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    open: state.open,
})
```

in this function, `state` is the root state. Ie, the one produced by the rootReducer. This state looks like:

```
{
  content: {
    open: // some boolean
  }
}
```

So to access it, you need to do:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    open: state.content.open,
})
```

---

PS, since you're using typescript, you should be able to do better than `any` for the type. At the very least, you could do this:

```
// in the file with the root reducer:
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    content: ContentReducer
});
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

// And then use it elsewhere like:
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    open: state.content.open,
})
```

Comment: Ohh, I see now. This fixed my issue, thanks for explaining it out as well and the typescript tip.

Answer (score 0):

mapStateToProps gets your root reducer state - so use state.content.open instead of state.open.